# How to Check if data exists with in the database and display error

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to have an error appear where if a user submits data for the same date they should not be allowed to do this. 
Im not too sure on how to do this, but have give it a stab but doesnt work.  i am unsure on how to get the reader working.

```
public string conString = "***ConnectionString***";

    private void mileage_submit_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (location_comboBox.Text == "" || mileage_textbox.Text == "" || other_location_textBox.Text == "" || other_mileage_textBox.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fill all required fields", ("Validation"), MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
            con.Open();
            if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)

            {
                string query = "INSERT INTO Mileage_Table(eb_number , Date, Location, Mileage, Other_location, Other_Miles, Total_Miles) values(@eb_number, @Date, @Location, @Mileage, @Other_location,@Other_Miles, @Total_Miles)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@eb_number", SqlDbType.Text).Value = Username_Mileage_lbl.Text.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Location", SqlDbType.Text).Value = location_comboBox.Text.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mileage", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Decimal.Parse(mileage_textbox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Other_Location", SqlDbType.Text).Value = other_location_textBox.Text.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Other_Miles", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Decimal.Parse(other_mileage_textBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Parse(Mileage_dateTimePicker.Text).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                decimal b = Convert.ToDecimal(mileage_textbox.Text);
                decimal c = Convert.ToDecimal(other_mileage_textBox.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Total_Miles", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToString(b + c);


                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SingleRow))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader.HasRows == true)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Date = " + reader[7].ToString() + "Already Exists");
                        }
                    }
                }
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                decimal TotalMiles = b + c;
                MessageBox.Show(TotalMiles + " Miles has been Logged");
                con.Close();
```

Comment: It's not working as you're calling ExecuteReader on an `INSERT` statement. What has to be unique for the data to be rejected? All of it, or just some parts?

Comment: Start by telling us what the issue is

Comment: If a user submits a date that already exists in the database it should not show up on the database.  There should be a messageBox displaying  that you have already submitted data for today @stuartd

Comment: Are you still in trouble there?

Comment: @T.S yes still in trouble on this one. cannot figure it out

Comment: did you see my answer?

Comment: yes but i an not sure how to apply it to my code.  im not sure what to change within the c# that i have

Comment: I think, its pretty clear. You need to make SQL call that contains `IF exists/INSERT` with criteria identifying record. Then you evaluate output of this execution for records affected. If records affected = 0, `exists` found record and insert has not ran. Otherwise `exists` has not find anything and insert succeeded. Example: `if not exists (select 1 from users where username = 'tony') insert into users values ('tony', 'tony@company.com');` This is simple. And tables can be different in `exists` and `insert`

Comment: so do i change my current SQL statement and put If NOT Exists(select from table where datecolumn = @myDateParam) right before the insert INTO Mileage_Table statement ?

Comment: yep! that what you need to do. And drop using data reader - see my answer

Comment: Your a wizard. got it. thanks soo much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Sql Server, one way you can do it, using the following SQL

```sql
If NOT Exists(select from table where datecolumn = @myDateParam)
    Insert Into table (col list) values (@param list);
```

Then you call this sql using

```
int retVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery( ..  ); // for plain sql number of affected rows returned. 0 - would mean nothing inserted
MessageBox.Show((retVal > 0 ? "Record Inserted" : "Record with specific date already existed"));
```

Now, if you want to output inserted values using `cmd.ExecuteReader`, you need to add to your insert Sql `OUTPUT INSERTED` clause https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017